# Dynamically added directives not responding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am building an app which loads some data from server and according to this data includes (appends) directives into the dom.
Here is the main page html:

```
<div ng-repeat="type in bet.bet_types">
    <div ng-include src="getBetTypeById(type.id)"></div>
</div>
```

Here is the `getBetTypeById(id)` function from the scope:

```
    $scope.getBetTypeById = function(id)
    {
        switch(id)
        {
            case 1:
                return '/views/partials/1.html';
                break;  
...
```

Here is the 1.html:

```
<test-test bettype={{type}}></test-test>
```

here is the tets-test directive:

```
var app = angular.module('soccerWinner', []);

app.directive('test-test', function()
{
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope:
        {
            bettype: '='
        },
        templateUrl: '/views/partials/directives/bettaype_soccer_winner.html',
        controller: function()
        {
            alert('dfd');
        }
    };
});
```

And here is the `bettaype_soccer_winner.html`:

```
<h2>test</h2>
```

There is no errors in the console but there is also no alert shown, as seen is the directive controller.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: You forgot to add `1.html` source code. Please add it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change directive name to `testTest`. It should be camelcase in definition.

> Angular normalizes an element's tag and attribute name to determine which elements match which directives. We typically refer to directives by their case-sensitive camelCase normalized name (e.g. ngModel). However, since HTML is case-insensitive, we refer to directives in the DOM by lower-case forms, typically using dash-delimited attributes on DOM elements (e.g. ng-model).

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive