# Error with binding an attribute value - angular include and directives

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, web, angularjs-directive

I am trying to include some directives dynamically according some data I receive from my server. I have asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24360468/dynamically-added-directives-not-responding) so before and now the directive is uploaded, but there is some error I see in the console, here is what I get: `Syntax Error: Token 'type' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column 3 of the expression [{{type}}] starting at [type}}].`

Here is the main page html:

```
<div ng-repeat="type in bet.bet_types">
    <div ng-include src="getBetTypeById(type.id)"></div>
</div>
```

Here is the `getBetTypeById(id)` function from the scope:

```
    $scope.getBetTypeById = function(id)
    {
        switch(id)
        {
            case 1:
                return '/views/partials/1.html';
                break;  
...
```

Here is the 1.html:

```
<test-test bettype={{type}}></test-test>
```

here is the tets-test directive:

```
var app = angular.module('soccerWinner', []);

app.directive('testTest', function()
{
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope:
        {
            bettype: '='
        },
        templateUrl: '/views/partials/directives/bettaype_soccer_winner.html',
        controller: function()
        {
            alert('dfd');
        }
    };
});
```

And here is the `bettaype_soccer_winner.html`:

```
<h2>test</h2>
```

There is no alert after the directives are loaded, and the above error is seen in the console.

What is wrong with what I do? I believe that the issue is related to the line of code `<test-test bettype={{type}}></test-test>`

Here is a sample of an type:

```
{"id":1,"name":"Winning Team or Tie","description":"Choose the winnig team.","schema":"{\n\t            \t'winnerId': 'integer',\n                    'options:' []\n\t            }","created_at":"2014-06-22 13:13:07","updated_at":"2014-06-22 13:13:07","pivot":{"bet_id":1,"bet_type_id":1},"userBet":""}
```

Comment: How does it look data coming from server?

Comment: With service and http.get. Then I put the Data I need to betTypes

Comment: What if you just `ng-include` the file without `getBetTypeById(id)`. Does it work then?

Comment: Do you mean just to put the src without the function? Hard coded?

Comment: Can you post some sample data you receive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be passing a model into the directive. Not the expression. Remove curly brackets, that should do the trick.

```
<test-test bettype="type"></test-test>
```

cheers